# Django create ManytoOne relation in one form

Tags: python, django, forms, input, foreign-keys

I am trying to develop a form where the user would be able to achieve this :

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaaKi.png)

So the form would have :

- a TextField for the name
- a TextField for the description
- a TextField for the addresses that would be entered by the User as a list

According to you, what would be the most appropriate approach to do so?

Thank you very much !

Comment: In a relational database, you make an extra model `Address` with a `ForeignKey` to `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import models

class Address(models.Model):
    address = models.TextField()

class UserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    addresses = models.ManyToMany(Address)
```

You can create the models and integrate them by the above code. One user can set multiple addresses to him, on the other side, one address can be assigned into many users. so Many To Many relationships can be fruitful to this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. it is exactly what I implemented. however, how do I display the address field in my form? I don't want to display a select field from the Foreign Key but the address field directly. Thanks

Comment: I think this video can help you from the scratch   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3iytAmzuNQ